# String evaluation for calling getters and setters

Tags: java, evaluation

I'm trying to evaluate a java path object expression in order to call the getters or setters. 
For example, the following expression **object1.object2.attribute1** should execute a code like this `obj.getObject2().getAttribute1();`

For that, I have a configuration file like this :

```
<grid_configuration>
    <injection>
        <cell>
            <position_X>1</position_X>
            <position_Y>2</position_Y>
            <type>Double</type>
            <expression>object1.attribute1</expression>
        </cell>
        <cell>
            <position_X>1</position_X>
            <position_Y>2</position_Y>
            <type>Double</type>
            <expression>object1.object2.attribute1</expression>
        </cell>
    </injection>
<grid_configuration>
```

And a service like this :

```
 <T> void injectData(GridConfiguration conf, T obj, Grid out);
```

The Grid object has a method `void setValue(int x, int y, String value);`

And my implementation

```
<T> void injectData(GridConfiguration conf, T obj, Grid out) {
    for(Cell c : conf.getCells()) {
        int x = c.getPositionX();
        int y = c.getPositionY();
        String value = evaluateExpression(obj, c.getExpression());

        out.setValue(x, y, value);
    }
}
```

The question is :

**Is there a java function, library or something else that helps me to build a method `<T> String evaluateExpression(T obj, String expression);`**

Otherwise, I need to do introspection on the object ... But I'm not particularly confortable with that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no built-in thing in java for this. Even similar mechanics (like JSP's Expression Language) use reflection to evaluate statements like those.

Comment: reflection is the keyword for that....

Comment: I'd advise that you get over your discomfort and implement this functionality using reflection APIs. You can then look at other implementations like SPE, just to compare with your own..

Comment: Is this part of a bigger project or would you be comfortable with using a different language very similar to Java?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. So I have no choice,  I'm going to find out more about reflection and build my own implementation.   
 @Assem Bansal that's actually part of a bigger Java project. But I'm curious,  what language was in your mind.    
 Anyway I'll post the result of my work once done. Thanks again.